# How to add an "instead of insert" trigger in SQLAlchemy ? (to modify a view)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I try to translate a DDL code from a book to SQLAlchemy core syntax ([see this document in french](https://staff.info.unamur.be/dbm/Documents/Ouvrages/Dunod-2015/Chapitres/Chapitre-21/JLH-A21-Production-de-code.pdf)).

I have troubles to figure out how to translate this part:

```
create trigger TRG_RAPPORT_INSERT
instead of insert on RAPPORT
for each row
declare I number
begin
   select select count(*) in :I from DOCUMENT
   where  ID_DOC = new.ID_DOC;
   if I = 1 then
      abort();
   end if;
   insert into _DOCUMENT(ID_Doc,D.Titre,estRAPPORT)
          values(new.ID_Doc,new.Titre,1);
   insert into _RAPPORT(ID_Doc,Code_Rapport,Projet)
          values(new.ID_Doc,new.Code_Rapport,new.Projet);
end;
```

Where `DOCUMENT` is a view (I used [this recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/Views) to create it).

I found in [SQLAchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/ddl.html?highlight=execute_at#controlling-ddl-sequences) that I might should use an event, but I don't know which one regarding [the list](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#schema-events).